# Guess the number game, error.

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a game I am currently trying to make. I am coding this game in python 3.4. it doesn't run.

```
    # this is a guess the number game!   

import random    
guesses = 0     
name = input("what is your name?")    
number = random.randint(1, 20)    
print = name + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20..."    
while guesses << 7:
    guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess."))    
    guesses = guesses + 1    
    if guess < number:
        print ("your guess is too low!")    
    if guess > number:
        print ("your guess is too high!")    
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    guesses = str(guesses)
    print ("Good job," + name + "you guessed my number in" +guesses +"guesses!")
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print ("Nah dude, better luck next time!")
```

Comment: In what way, exactly, does it not run? Include expected output, actual output, error messages, and so on.

Comment: Although I can see several syntax errors and typos, such as the indented lines at the top, `print = ...`, `guess << 7`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use `<` instead of `<<`. `<<` and `>>` are bit shift operators to the left and right respectively.

Your last two if conditions are also outside your loop, and don't make much sense. You're already checking `if guess == number` once and breaking if that condition is met. `if guess != number` your already checking this by using `<` and `>` respectively.

`print = ...`? `print` syntax is `print(some_stuff, ...)`. Indentation is also off at the top, but assuming that's just due to posting your first question.

Also, `raw_input` is for python2 it's just `input` in python3. You could clean the print statements up some with `%` formatters or using `.format`.

Fixed code: (Python 3 version since that's whats tagged in the question...)

```
import random

name = input("what is your name?")
number = random.randint(1, 20)
#print("%s I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20..." % name)
print(name + " I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20...")

guesses = 0
while guesses < 7:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess."))
    guesses += 1

    if guess < number:
        print ("your guess is too low!")

    elif guess > number:
        print ("your guess is too high!")

    else:
        #print("Good job %s you guessed my number in %d guesses" % (name, guesses))
        print ("Good job, " + name + " you guessed my number in " + str(guesses) + " guesses!")
        break
```

Comment: so with your much prettier code, i still get an error. this error says: syntaxerror: 'break' outside loop

Comment: Did you try a copy and paste? `break` is definitely inside the loop here, it might be a copy / paste or perhaps an editing error adjusting code. As the error says the `break` must be within the loop and in this case within the `else` to break the `while` loop at the proper point.

Comment: didnt want to copy and paste. i needed to fix what was wrong to visually see what was wrong. anyways, its fixed and working great. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your program. Always include errors you get in your question. Given the syntax error you are making first get your hands dirty on python interpreter by executing simple commands.  Below should help. Below is in Python 2, for Python 3 replace, `raw_input()` with `input` and `print 'something'` with `print ('something')`

**1st Solution:**

```
import random

name = raw_input("Hello! What is your name?\n")
print "Well, " + name + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20"
no = random.randint(1,20)
guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess\n"))
count =1

while guess != no:    
    if guess < no:
        print "Your guess is too low."                 
    if guess > no:
        print "Your guess is too high"
    count +=1
    guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess\n"))

print "Good job, %s! You guessed my number in %d guesses!" % (name ,count)
```

**2nd Solution:**

```
import random

def check():
    global count  # good example of use of global
    guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess\n"))
    if guess == no:
        print "Good job, %s! You guessed my number in %d guesses!" %(name,count)
    elif guess < no:
        print "Your guess is too low."
        count +=1        
        check()          
    else:
        print "Your guess is too high"
        count +=1
        check()

name = raw_input("Hello! What is your name?\n")
print "Well, " + name + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20"
no = random.randint(1,20)
global count
count  =1
check()
```

Comment: using multiple `if`'s is redundant here. It'll check each of those conditions instead of stopping on the one it passes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes good, little changes can make it run!

```
import random    
guesses = 0     
name = raw_input("what is your name?") # use input() is using Python 3
number = random.randint(1, 20)    
print name + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20..."    
while guesses < 7:
    guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess."))    
    guesses = guesses + 1    
    if guess < number:
        print ("your guess is too low!")    
    if guess > number:
        print ("your guess is too high!")    
    if guess == number:
        break
if guesses == number:
    print ("Good job,", name, "you guessed my number in", guesses, "guesses!")
if guesses != number:
    number = str(number)
    print ("Nah dude, better luck next time!", "The number is", number)
```